# Avoiding duplicate code when performing operation on different object properties

Tags: algorithm, oop, design-patterns, code-duplication

I have recently run into a problem which has had me thinking in circles. Assume that I have an object of type O with properties O.A and O.B. Also assume that I have a collection of instances of type O, where O.A and O.B are defined for each instance.

Now assume that I need to perform some operation (like sorting) on a collection of O instances using *either* O.A or O.B, but not both at any given time. My original solution is as follows.

Example -- just for demonstration, not production code:

```
public class O {
    int A;
    int B;
}

public static class Utils {
    public static void SortByA (O[] collection) {
        // Sort the objects in the collection using O.A as the key. Note: this is custom sorting logic, so it is not simply a one-line call to a built-in sort method.
    }

    public static void SortByB (O[] collection) {
        // Sort the objects in the collection using O.B as the key. Same logic as above.
    }
}
```

What I would love to do is this...

```
public static void SortAgnostic (O[] collection, FieldRepresentation x /* some non-bool, non-int variable representing whether to chose O.A or O.B as the sorting key */) {
    // Sort by whatever "x" represents...
}
```

... but creating a new, highly-specific type that I will have to maintain just to avoid duplicating a few lines of code *seems* unnecessary to me. Perhaps I am incorrect on that (and I am sure someone will correct me if that statement is wrong :D), but that is my current thought nonetheless.

Question: What is the best way to implement this method? The logic that I have to implement is difficult to break down into smaller methods, as it is already fairly optimized. At the root of the issue is the fact that I need to perform the same operation using different properties of an object. I would like to stay away from using codes/flags/etc. in the method signature *if possible* so that the solution can be as robust as possible.

**Note:** When answering this question, please approach it from an algorithmic point of view. I am aware that some language-specific features may be suitable alternatives, but I have encountered this problem before and would like to understand it from a relatively language-agnostic viewpoint. Also, please do not constrain responses to sorting solutions only, as I have only chosen it as an example. The real question is how to avoid code duplication when performing an identical operation on two different properties of an object.

Comment: I feel that your problem is related more to language-specific features. I don't understand the "algorithmic point of view". The only logic that there is, is happening in your sort method. If you didn't want to add flags to choose the property to use, you can use an anonymous inner class (in case of java) or inline functions (in case of Javascript) to let your sort method be agnostic.

Comment: @seeta -- Thanks for your comment. By "algorithmic point of view" I simply meant that I would like to solve this problem across several projects I am working (such as javascript with jquery, c#, java, etc). Each has different features that could help, but I would like to know the "least common denominator solution" that can be applied to the largest number of languages without drastic changes.

Comment: Basically you seem to want a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (for Java at least). Or you want to use Reflection (which is rather language-specific).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"The real question is how to avoid code duplication when performing an identical operation on two different properties of an object."**

This is a very good question as this situation arises all the time. I think, one of the best ways to deal with this situation is to use the following pattern.

```
public class O {
    int A;
    int B;
}

public doOperationX1() {
   doOperationX(something to indicate which property to use);
}

public doOperationX2() {
   doOperationX(something to indicate which property to use);
}
private doOperationX(input ) {
     // actual work is done here
}
```

In this pattern, the actual implementation is performed in a private method, which is called by public methods, with some extra information. For example, in this case, it can be 
doOperationX(A), or doOperationX(B), or something like that.

My Reasoning: In my opinion this pattern is optimal as it achieves two main requirements:

1. It keeps the public interface descriptive and clear, as it keeps operations separate, and avoids flags etc that you also mentioned in your post. This is good for the client.
2. From the implementation perspective, it prevents duplication, as it is in one place. This is good for the development.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach this I think is to internalize the behavior of choosing the sort field to the class `O` itself. This way the solution can be language-agnostic.

The implementation in Java could be using an Abstract class for `O`, where the purpose of the abstract method `getSortField()` would be to return the field to sort by. All that the invocation logic would need to do is to implement the abstract method to return the desired field.

```
O o = new O() {
    public int getSortField() {
        return A;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be reduced to obtaining the value of the specified field from the given object so it can be use for sorting purposes, or,

```
TField getValue(TEntity entity, string fieldName)
{
    // Return value of field "A" from entity,
    // implementation depends on language of choice, possibly with 
    // some sort of reflection support
}
```

This method can be used to substitute comparisons within the sorting algorithm,

```
if (getValue(o[i], "A")) > getValue(o[j], "A"))
{
    swap(i, j);
}
```

The field name can then be parametrized, as,

```
public static void SortAgnostic (O[] collection, string fieldName) 
{
    if (getValue(collection[i], fieldName)) > getValue(collection[j], fieldName))
    {
        swap(i, j);
    }

    ...
}
```

which you can use like `SortAgnostic(collection, "A")`.

Some languages allow you to express the field in a more elegant way,

```
public static void SortAgnostic (O[] collection, Expression fieldExpression) 
{
    if (getValue(collection[i], fieldExpression)) > 
        getValue(collection[j], fieldExpression))
    {
        swap(i, j);
    }

    ...
}
```

which you can use like `SortAgnostic(collection, entity => entity.A)`.

And yet another option can be passing a pointer to a function which will return the value of the field needed,

```
public static void SortAgnostic (O[] collection, Function getValue) 
{
    if (getValue(collection[i])) > getValue(collection[j]))
    {
        swap(i, j);
    }
    ...
}
```

which given a function,

```
TField getValueOfA(TEntity entity)
{
    return entity.A;
}
```

and passing it like `SortAgnostic(collection, getValueOfA)`.

Answer (score 0):

"... but creating a new, highly-specific type that I will have to maintain just to avoid duplicating a few lines of code seems unnecessary to me"

That is why you should use available tools like frameworks or other typo of code libraries that provide you requested solution.

When some mechanism is common that mean it can be moved to higher level of abstraction. When you can not find proper solution try to create own one. Think about the result of operation as not part of class functionality. The sorting is only a feature, that why it should not be part of your class from the beginning. Try to keep class as simple as possible.

Do not worry premature about the sense of having something small just because it is small. Focus on the final usage of it. If you use very often one type of sorting just create a definition of it to reuse it. You do not have to necessary create a utill class and then call it. Sometimes the base functionality enclosed in utill class is fair enough.

I assume that you use Java:

In your case the wheal was already implemented in person of [Collection#sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

To full fill it you could create a Enum type that implement Comparator interface with predefined sorting types.